# sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts Error

Tags: linux, sudo

[image: screenshot of terminal when using sudo]

I am getting this error whenever I use sudo on terminal, due to which I am unable to edit any file (permission issues) and moreover am unable to update my system. Is there any specific solution without re-installing system?

Comment: you know the sudo password???

Comment: It sounds like your PAM configuration has broken. Knowing how it's been broken is the difficult piece (it could be a broken module, or it could be the config file getting messed up).

Comment: Which Linux do you use? Ubuntu, Suse, ...?

Comment: @Hackaholic Yes I know my password, but its not prompting me to enter my password. As soon as I enter my password it shows me this error

Comment: @progsource ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Is this a server or a desktop system? Can you start synaptic or the graphical update center (I don't know the english name) and enter your password there?

Comment: This is a desktop system @userunknown

Comment: And what if you run synaptic or the like - where you are asked graphically for the password - same problem, or why do you specifically mention the terminal? To edit the sudoers file or specify a root password, booting in grub into the rescue mode should be sufficient. No need to reinstall the system.

Answer (score -1):

Since you seem to be able to login, it looks like `sudo` itself got screwed up. You will need a root password to clean up the mess, otherwise all you can do is reinstall. Once you login as root, here are the things to try:

1. Run `sudo` with `strace` and `LD_DEBUG`. Maybe an incorrect library was installed, or an important file got removed somehow. Once you identify the problematic file, try to reinstall the package it belongs to.
2. Check `sudo` config files (`/etc/sudoers` or whatever you have in `/etc/sudoers.d`). If you have modified these files recently, revert the changes.